# ¿Porque me sale este erro en Ruby "ActionController::UrlGenerationError"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lo que quiero conseguir es llegar a mi formulario para poder agregar información o nuevos registros pero el problema es que cuando le doy clic en agregar nuevo, me aparece una pestaña de error.

Controlador

```
 def new
           @serie = Serie.new();

  end

  def create
@folio = params[:serie][:folio];
   @serie = Serie.new({
      :folio => @folio
      });
   if @serie.save()
      redirect_to series_path, :notice => "La Serie ha sido insertada";
   else
      render "new";
   end
  end
```

Vista

```
<section class="formulario">


<%= form_for @serie do |f| %> 

<form>

<label>Hola Mundo</label>>
   </form>

   <% end %>



</section>
```

Este es el error que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a que dirección te está direccionando?

Comment: que rutas te salen cuando pones el comando rake routes ?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu codigo tiene ; debes de quitarlo rails no utiliza esa sintaxis.

Esta mal tu  `redirect_to series_path, :notice => "La Serie ha sido insertada"`

cambialo por `redirect_to  @serie, :notice => "La Serie ha sido insertada"`